# Order voucher discounts are removed while fetching the OrderData

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, storefront

I have below line of code to populate the order details page. For orders enjoying voucher discounts on executing the below line I notice the order, orderentry are modified. Also I notice the order entries discounts are removed thereby entry's discount is lost.

> final OrderData orderData = b2bOrderFacade.getOrderDetailsForCode(orderCode);

Whats wrong with the above code? Why order is modified?

Hybris version: 5.3.0.6

Comment: did you override the default B2bOrderFacade?

Comment: No. Method called is de.hybris.platform.b2bacceleratorfacades.order.impl.DefaultB2BOrderFacade.getOrderDetailsForCode()

Comment: You must have overrided the orderConverter/OrderPopulator because in the ootb code discounts are properly populated. (check AbstractOrderPopulator). I've checked on 5.4 however, maybe the code in 5.3 is different.

Comment: Let me check and get back